# PHP cURL POSTFIELDS to RESTful Service

Tags: java, php, xml, web-services, rest

I'm developing a project and i'm with some dificulties on how to post data to a java restful webservice, using php curl.

**SQL :**

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS POST_TESTE;
CREATE DATABASE POST_TESTE;
USE POST_TESTE;

CREATE TABLE GRAU  (
ID_GRAU             TINYINT         UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
DESCRICAO_GRAU      VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE GRAU ADD CONSTRAINT PK_GRAU PRIMARY KEY (ID_GRAU);
ALTER TABLE GRAU CHANGE ID_GRAU ID_GRAU TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

INSERT INTO GRAU (DESCRICAO_GRAU) VALUES ('CET');
INSERT INTO GRAU (DESCRICAO_GRAU) VALUES ('Licenciatura');
INSERT INTO GRAU (DESCRICAO_GRAU) VALUES ('Pós-Licenciatura');
INSERT INTO GRAU (DESCRICAO_GRAU) VALUES ('Pós-Graduação');
INSERT INTO GRAU (DESCRICAO_GRAU) VALUES ('Mestrado');
INSERT INTO GRAU (DESCRICAO_GRAU) VALUES ('Doutoramento');
```

In Netbeans, just created a web application called "Teste" and then restful webservices from database, where i selected the table created above. Created 2 packages, 1st (entity) which theres a class related with the table vars, and 2nd (service) which is related with the services provided.

So our consuming services url is http:// localhost:8080/Teste/resources/entity.grau

**Grau.java :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "grau")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"idGrau", "descricaoGrau"})
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Grau.findAll", query = "SELECT g FROM Grau g"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Grau.findByIdGrau", query = "SELECT g FROM Grau g WHERE g.idGrau = :idGrau"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Grau.findByDescricaoGrau", query = "SELECT g FROM Grau g WHERE g.descricaoGrau = :descricaoGrau")})
public class Grau implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_GRAU")
    private Short idGrau;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    @Column(name = "DESCRICAO_GRAU")
    private String descricaoGrau;
```

**GrauFacadeREST.java :**

```
@Stateless
@Path("entity.grau")
public class GrauFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Grau> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "TestePU")
private EntityManager em;

public GrauFacadeREST() {
    super(Grau.class);
}

@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void create(Grau entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}

@PUT
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void edit(Grau entity) {
    super.edit(entity);
}
```

There are more services developed, like GET, DELETE services, but i only want to understand this two.

I have developed a basic html with one input text which post the data to a .php, which this .php objective is to catch the info and post it to, for example, the **create** method, to add a new grau to the table.

**teste.html :**

```
<html><body>
<form action="teste.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="text1" /></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submeter" />
</form>
</body></html>
```

**teste.php :**

```
<?php

$var=$_POST['text1'];

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<graus/>');
$teste = $xml->addChild('grau');
$teste -> addChild('idGrau', '7');
$teste -> addChild('descricaoGrau', $var);
$teste1 = $xml->addChild('grau');
$teste1 -> addChild('idGrau', '8');
$teste1 -> addChild('descricaoGrau', $var);

//$xml="<graus><grau><idgrau>7</idgrau><descricaograu>asdf</descricaograu></grau><grau><idgrau>8</idgrau><descricaograu>asdf</descricaograu></grau></graus>";

/* $xml = array(
        "idgrau" => '7',
        "descricaograu" => $var,
);
*/

print($xml->asXML());

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8080/Teste/resources/entity.grau/');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$data=curl_exec($ch); 

if (curl_errno($ch)){
    echo curl_error($ch);
    exit;
}   
var_dump($data);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I have tried this in diferent ways changing the sending postfields, injecting arrays in postfields, etc etc, still saying the same error:

HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Bad Request).

This is a responsive xml through a .php developed, when user consumes the findAll() method.

```
<graus>
    <grau>
        <idGrau>1</idGrau>
        <descricaoGrau>CET</descricaoGrau>
    </grau>
    <grau>
        <idGrau>2</idGrau>
        <descricaoGrau>Licenciatura</descricaoGrau>
    </grau>
    <grau>
        <idGrau>3</idGrau>
        <descricaoGrau>Pós-Licenciatura</descricaoGrau>
    </grau>
    <grau>
        <idGrau>4</idGrau>
        <descricaoGrau>Pós-Graduação</descricaoGrau>
    </grau>
    <grau>
        <idGrau>5</idGrau>
        <descricaoGrau>Mestrado</descricaoGrau>
    </grau>
    <grau>
        <idGrau>6</idGrau>
        <descricaoGrau>Doutoramento</descricaoGrau>
    </grau>
</graus>
```

If anybody could help i would be thankful, because i have lost a lot of time trying this and still didnt understand how to do it.

Comment: what you get if you directly run webserive url into browser ? you xml missing <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  ??

Comment: if i run the http:// localhost:8080/Teste/resources/entity.grau is the same response as run the .php that gives the the xml above. the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> isn't needed because if you inspect element you can see it there.

Comment: -> http://i49.tinypic.com/2exx99d.png

Comment: Try to add content length into header option of curl 'Content-Length: '.strlen($xml)

Comment: @GBD doesn't work, gives Grizzly/1.9.46 Bad Request

Comment: does this article help you http://xebee.xebia.in/2011/12/30/example-of-restful-webservice-with-xml-and-json-using-maven-jaxb-jersey-tomcat-and-curl/